# Save and load UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview, save, load

I want to save and load  image in  `UIImageView`
I have already tried some code but it doesn't work.
The Code i have tried:

*Save:*

```
UIImage *image = ...;
NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

*Load:*

```
NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cachedImagePath]];
```

But these code doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want to save image in document directory folder
here is the way to save image:

```
- (void)saveImage: (UIImage*)image
{
if (image != nil)
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
}
```

to get image from document directory:

```
- (UIImage*)loadImage
{
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:
[NSString stringWithString: @"test.png"] ];
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:path];
return image;
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Globally declare imageView

```
UIImageView *imageView;//if u create imageView in interfaceBuilder. then u can replace this line by creating outlet of ur imageView
```

for loading image:

```
//Loading image in imageView
NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image.png"];
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cachedImagePath])
{
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:cachedImagePath]];
    if (image)
    {
        imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];//Dont do this, if u created imageView using interFace builder
        [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, 100, 200, 200)];//Dont do this, if u created imageView using interFace builder
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];//Dont do this, if u created imageView using interFace builder
        [imageView setImage:image];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Unsupported File");
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Image not Found in the path");
}
```

for saving image:

```
UIImage *image = imageView.image;
if (image)
{
    NSString *cachedFolderPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
    NSString *cachedImagePath = [cachedFolderPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"imageSaved.png"];
    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:cachedImagePath atomically:YES];
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:cachedImagePath])
    {
        NSLog(@"File Created");
    }
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"No image to save");
}
```